# Dynamically created program listing

Tags: listings

Is there a way to have a easy to change value in program listing?
Something along these lines:

```
\newcommand{\variable}{2}
```

And then having somewhere

```
\begin{lstlisting}
...
i *= \variable;
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

I would like to keep the format, so I don't want to end and start another listing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You should use the `mathescape` option provided by [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings):

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
...
i *= $\variable$;
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

This escapes back to LaTeX, where `\variable` has a different meaning than inside `lstlisting`. Here's a complete MWE showing the use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\newcommand{\variable}{2}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
...
i *= \variable;
...
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
...
i *= $\variable$;
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. One minor thing, the font of    the escaped text is different from font of listing, are there any options to use the font of the listing in escaped text?
One more thing, any chance of doing arithmetics? Lets say I assign a value "1" to command, could I add 1 to it a display it in program listing?